# Triggering a picture with esp32-cam and GPIO13

Tags: esp32, esp32-cam

I'm trying to trigger a picture using the GPIO13 of an esp32-cam, AI Thinker model.
I'm using that example as a base:
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-pir-motion-detector-photo-capture/
but instead of the PIR/Transistor combination, I'm using a press button with a pull-up resistor that pulls the GPIO13 pin down when pressed, simulating the PIR signal.
I'm feeding the esp-32 cam with a 5V power supply and the button circuit with the 3.3v
pin of the esp32, all grounded.
All hardware, SD card and so on is tested ok, I got the right voltages and I can see the GPIO13 Pin going to ground on my scope, but I just doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Edit 1: I'm using the ESP32-CAM-MB USB Board

Comment: What is it printing on the serial output?

Comment: I cannot watch the serial port while running this, as the board doesn't have a USB port.

Comment: @brunobhr Then use your programmer board to see the serial output. The same that you're using for flashing the chip.

Comment: You cannot run the board in flashing configuration.

Comment: *I* don't seem to have any problem running an ESP32-CAM while looking at its serial connection. I don't understand why you are. However, you can at least make a function that blinks an LED call that from places where error messages are also printed. You can add to the question what you find out.

Comment: If you're using the ESP32-CAM-MB: The -MB has an usual requirement with respect to control signals. It will not show you sketch serial output in just any terminal software. If you use the latest IDE and select the correct board it will set the control signals as necessary will show sketch output, including your diagnostic messages.

Comment: @timemage Thank you. Unfortunately my -MB model makes it impossible to hook up external circuits when plugged in. I'll have to desolder it and re-solder longer pins, or find a way to read the serial monitor on an LCD

Comment: I don't understand, but then I can't see your wiring either. If more information shows up in the question, e..g if you post wiring and/or take the LED blinking suggestion, maybe there will be some way of helping.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [specs of the cam board](https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/esp32-cam), I see that `GPIO13` has the function `HS2_DATA3`, suggesting that the SD card is using that pin (which is also corroborated by [this article](https://dr-mntn.net/2021/02/using-the-sd-card-in-1-bit-mode-on-the-esp32-cam-from-ai-thinker).)

This may or may not be a problem, as the state of `GPIO13` is only relevant for sleep/wakeup when the chip is sleeping, and only relevant for SD card access when the chip is running; but there is an external addon: your pullup resistor on the button is still there when the chip is running. The PIR module from the tutorial that you're trying to replace probably has an open collector output (floating when inactive, pulled LOW when active).

My best hunch is to get rid of the pullup resistor on your button, so that the pin is floating during SD card access.

There still is the possibility that you then interfere with the SD card data when you keep the button pressed. If that is the case, you may need to put a resistor in *series* with the button, so that the wake-up signal is weaker than the SD card data signal (start at 100KOhm and reduce until wake-up works).

If that isn't it, the question is lacking details. As you did not even post a description of what exactly "just does not work", first thing would be to produce a minimal sketch just to test sleep/wakeup via GPIO13 and post that here.

Comment: Thank you, but how does the code provided in the link deals with that? I'm just replacing a signal by another..

Comment: Also, getting rid of the pullup resistor and adding any value in series doesn't change anything.

Comment: And doesn't work means it's not acting as intended eg. no picture on the SD Card.

Comment: The code in the example link is doing wakeup through GPIO13

Comment: @brunobhr Yes, you're replacing one signal with another, but we don't know what type of signal you're replacing. The PIR from the tutorial probably provides a weak open collector output to ground, but your button originally is a strong push-pull output.

Comment: @brunobhr You'll need to tell what exactly is "not working". An image on the SD card is the desired end result, but there are a lot of steps to check beforehand: Can you flash the cam board successfully? Which output on the serial line comes up after flashing? Does the chip go to sleep successfully? Does it wake up successfully? If no, can you make it wake up by other means (e.g. taking a wire to pull GPIO13 to 3.3V or GND)? What is printed on the Serial output after waking up? Are there any status LEDs on the board, and if yes, when are they lit up?

Comment: Sorry but have you read the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, I have read the link, but those tutorials never go into the details you need if you're altering the setup in the slightest.

Comment: I'm just trying to get a pin to ground, this example works according to the comments. Now asking me if I can flash my board is not gonna get us somewhere I think. Thank you anyway